# cocreateinstance crashes on 32bit

Tags: c++, com

I'm trying to instantiate WMEncoder with CoCreateInstance() function, it's working fine on 64bit but crashes the program on 32bit os version.

```
HRESULT hr = E_FAIL;
IWMEncoder2 *g_pEncoder = NULL;

hr = CoInitialize(NULL);
if (FAILED(hr))
    return hr;

hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_WMEncoder, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IWMEncoder2, (void**)&g_pEncoder);
if (FAILED(hr)) {
    CoUninitialize();
    return hr;
}
```

Even on 64bit it generates access violation exception. here is windbg output:

```
...
ModLoad: 75580000 761ca000   C:\Windows\syswow64\SHELL32.dll
ModLoad: 6fb40000 6fbc4000   C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.7601.17514_none_ec83dffa859149af\COMCTL32.dll
ModLoad: 74a10000 74a29000   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\OLEPRO32.DLL
ModLoad: 74f70000 74f86000   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\CRYPTSP.dll
ModLoad: 74a50000 74a8b000   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rsaenh.dll
ModLoad: 73110000 7311e000   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\RpcRtRemote.dll
(1d48.1ea8): Access violation - code c0000005 (first chance)
First chance exceptions are reported before any exception handling.
This exception may be expected and handled.
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Media Components\Encoder\WMEncEng.dll - 
eax=08b7801f ebx=001807a8 ecx=00000000 edx=00000000 esi=00454c28 edi=00734258
eip=00734258 esp=0280f574 ebp=0280f5bc iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na po nc
cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00010202
00734258 c7442404284c4500 mov     dword ptr [esp+4],454C28h ss:002b:0280f578=001807a8
```

Comment: And what does hr equal to?

Comment: it crashes the program before returning an error code.

Comment: where exactly (what line) it crashes?

Comment: when calling CoCreateInstance(), it doesnt return

Comment: but when i change the context to CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER, it fails with error 0x80040154

Comment: The code is `0x80040154` `REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG` "Class not registered" so you apparently don't have respective COM class available to your code. And the class belongs to Windows Media Encoder you supposedly just don't have installed. See https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/27d10f58-34a6-47c0-8492-6bbb10be39f6/cocreateinstance-clsidwmencoder-fail

Comment: do i need to register it explicitly, all i have done is install WMEncoder package found at microsoft website, and it worked very well on 64bit version

Comment: i did. i installed both WMEncoderSDK and WMEncoder itself, im aware of that. the registry keys are there as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you only installed the 64-bit version, you won't be able to instantiate it in 32-bit code.

Comment: No, I installed the 32-bit version, and here is the link to it [http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17792](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17792)